# Does the sum of the reciprocals of the squared cube-free numbers "exist"?

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta

I know there is a formula for $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(k)}{k^s}=\zeta(s)^{-1}$, which in other words mean the sum over the square-free numbers, due to the present Mobius function.

A different result is $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\mu(k)|}{k^s}=\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)}$

How about the cube-frees? Looking for: $\displaystyle\sum_{k \text{ } cube-free}\frac{1}{k^2}$.

(Site is not loading the equations I posted in math mode. Oh well.)

Comment: (You had typos in your TeX that left mismatched braces in both equations)

Comment: Are you interested in _all_ cube-free numbers, or just squares that are cube-free? (There's a bit of a mismatch between the title and the post)

Comment: So a number is cube-free iff it can be written as $ab^2$, with $a,b$ square-free and $\gcd(a,b)=1$, right? (Not sure if that helps)

Comment: Thanks so much to whoever fixed my typo (Steven)!! I'm interested in knowing if a similar result for the sum of all squared cube-free reciprocals. Wow, I'm impressed to see that Google has already indexed this post, it matches a search I did and I came right back to my topic.

Comment: Omg, I'm truly a genius, haha, I know it sucks to brag, but I just found the sum of those numbers, haha.

Comment: Of course the sum exists (that is, converges), as it's a subsum of the sum of the reciprocals of all the squares, which converges. I think you are really asking whether there is a formula for it in terms of standard functions. If so, that's what the title should ask. And if you have found an answer, terrific – you should write it up, and post it as an answer.

Comment: @Gerry  I am  not asking about convergence I am asking whether the limit is explicitly known. Hence the double quotes in "exist". I should have explained it better though. (mod ed.)

Comment: So, have you found an answer, or haven't you? It's not clear from your "Omg" comment.

Comment: I definitely have, btw, not just that, I have found a lot of other amazing patterns in Number Theory, and am planning on publishing the results in a paper, so I've been typing formulas in Latex like there's no tomorrow. Unfortunately, this won't be even as hard as finding a decent place to publish this paper, as the establishment hates people who are not in the establishment (e.g., Universities, etc.) They boycott a lot the work of non academical people. If you have an idea who I can turn to to make my work known, please let me know.

Comment: You can start by posting an answer here to your question. We'll take it from there. Also, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry in it.

Comment: I have just read some guidelines for the arXivs and am emailing some of my former professors at USP, Brazil. It's been a long time though. I'm a little bit hesitant to post things online, because after you do that, you can't claim credit anymore, a zillion other people will show up claiming ownership, haha. I like Math, and I want to help advance it, but I need to be able to claim credit to what I created too. Are you a professor, btw?

Comment: Ok, just noticed that someone pointed me out to something in another question I had posted. So, yes, this may not be new, and I wanted to doublecheck cause I don't want to claim credit to something that's already taken. Let me have a look a Popovic's function.

Comment: Anything you post here gets a timestamp which should be sufficient for establishing priority.

Comment: I'm working on it, when I'm done I will post here as well. In the meantime, can you have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2759231/sum-of-the-cube-free-numbers-sum-k-1-infty-frac-mu-2kk2s.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Btw, if you'd be so kind to endorse me for an upload to the arXiv, I'd appreciate it. But I have asked a few of my former professors from back in 1995.

Comment: I don't think I have the qualifications to do that.

Comment: Gotchya, guess I'll have to keep on asking around then.