# Sum of the cube-free numbers $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\mu_{2}(k)|}{k^{s}}$

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta

I've come across a formula for $\mu_{2}(n)$ and am not sure if this formula is equal to Apostol's generalized Mobius function or [Popovici's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function#Popovici's_function).

I am not very knowledgeable about the work of these 2 people, so I would like some help to figure out if what I have is the same as what they've created.
I'm more confident that what I found is not equal to Apostol's, but not sure about Popovici's function.

Perhaps they're not the same if there is more than one way to compute the below, that is, the sum of the reciprocals of the cube-free numbers (raised to a power greater than 1):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\mu_{2}(k)|}{k^{s}}=\frac{\zeta(s)^2}{\zeta(2s)^2}.$$

Now, here's what I have (my version of $\mu_{2}$):

$$\mu_{2}(n)=\begin{cases}
    1, & \text{if $n$=1} \\
    (-2)^{k_{1}}, & \text{if $n$ is cube-free with $k_{1}$ single prime factors} \\
    0, & \text{if $n$ is not cube-free}.
\end{cases}$$

As for the 2 aforementioned results:

Popovici (1963) defined a generalised Mobius function $\mu_{k}=\mu\cdot ...\cdot \mu$ to be the $k$-fold Dirichlet convolution of the Mobius function with itself. It is thus again a multiplicative function with:

$\mu_{k}(p^a) = (-1)^a \binom{k}{a}$

For Apostol, please click link (too much trouble to type his equations here, he has them on the very first page):
http://emis.ams.org/journals/AUSM/C1-2/math2-4.pdf

Comment: Most unclear. Are you defining $\mu_2$ by the zeta-formula, and then asking whether your formula for $\mu_2$ is correct? What is Apostol's function? What is Popovici's function? (I know you give a link, but it's better to give the answer here). And why not just edit to remove the disconnect?

Comment: I am a new user and am having a hard time trying to edit the title, where is the link to do that Lol? Are you a professor btw? Btw I'm looking for someone who I can get an endorsement from, to publish a paper on the arXiv. Now, perhaps the above is unclear, but I'm not asking if my version of $\mu_{2}(n)$ is correct, I'm asking if it's the same as Popovi or Apostol's, I take it you don't know. But that is not even my biggest discovery, I need the endorsement for a more interesting result I found.

Comment: Nevermind the request for endorsement, I already saw your reply on the other topic.

Comment: As I think I've mentioned before, if you want to be sure I see a comment addressed to me, you have to put @Gerry in it. You have been able to edit your question; whatever you did to enable that, the same thing should work for editing the title. I don't know whether your version of $\mu_2$ is the same as those others, but I might be able to figure it out if you would edit a description of those others into the body of your question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Done, now have a look and see if you can determine if what they have is different than what I have. I believe my version is different from Apostol, but a different set of eyes is good to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

The Popovici function $\mu_2$ is multiplicative with $\mu_2(1)=\mu_2(p^0)=\dots=1$, $\mu_2(p)=-2$, $\mu_2(p^2)=1$, and $\mu_2(p^a)=0$ for $a\ge3$. Therefore, $\mu_2(n)=(-2)^r$ if $n$ is cubefree and there are $r$ primes $p$ such that $p$ divides $n$ but $p^2$ does not divide $n$, while $\mu_2(n)=0$ if $n$ is not cubefree. This agrees with the formula for $\mu_2$ in the question, provided "single prime factors" means primes $p$ such that $p$ divides $n$ but $p^2$ does not divide $n$.

Comment: Yes, single prime factors mean a prime factor that shows in the prime decomposition of $n$ with an exponent equal to 1. There you go, Popovici beat me to it, but I'm not surprised. Looking at this problem it became so easy to see what $\mu_{2}(n)$ should be in order to produce $\zeta(s)^{-2}$.